# Векторизована ли функция library()?

Tags: r

Векторизована ли функция `library()`?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не векторизована:

```
> library(c("mlr3", "xgboost"))
Error in library(c("mlr3", "xgboost")) : 'package' must be of length 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Векторизована, в том смысле, что название пакета это объект типа *name*,  а  преобразование

```
as.name(x)
```

выполняет

```
 as.vector(x, "symbol")
```

Comment: Преобразование в вектор ничего общего с векторизацией не имеет.